# is there any way to get value of a vagrant autocorrect port forward in a script?

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, vagrantfile, chef-solo

I'm using Vagrant and Chef-zero to deploy test servers and one of the attributes that the program I'm testing requires is it's service URL. 
With the following lines in my Vagrant file:

```
 config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8000, auto_correct: true
 ...
 chef.json = {
  'pywps' => {
    :serverurl => 'http://localhost:8000/cgi-bin/wps.py',
    ...
    }
   }
```

Everything works fine for the first VM I spin up but if I need a second (or something is already using port 8000) then Vagrant auto corrects my port but I need some way to put that port number into the serverurl variable.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK not off the shelf. You could make a Vagrant plugin to hook into the provisioning process and rewrite the data, but that is likely overkill.

Comment: I thinks its [correct](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/rRE68TgNGyI) - from this thread, you can see potential plugin that would read that : https://github.com/jordansissel/vagrant-port

Answer (score 3):

### From the shell:

The `vagrant port` command can give you this information, e.g. with:

```
vagrant port --guest 80
```

That would print out `8000` by default in your case -- or whatever the host port ended up being if it had to auto-correct it.

---

### *Things I tried which didn't work:*

(room for improvement for future answers...)

#### From Chef-zero:

I haven't used Chef-zero + Vagrant enough to know how to plug that in there, so I leave that as an exercise to those reading this. I will say, though, that you don't want to run this shell command from inside the Vagrantfile, becasue that will create recursive nastiness (as running this command, in turn, reads Vagrantfile).

#### From within Vagrantfile:

I suspect there either is or could be made to be a way to get at the info from within ruby inside the Vagrantfile, but I'm not sure how to do it.  Sadly, something like the following doesn't work:

```rb
theport = config.vm.networks.select do |type,options|
  type == :forwarded_port and options[:guest] == 80
end.map do |type, options|
  options[:host]
end.first
```

... because `theport` just gets what the host port for guest port 80 ***would*** be, prior to doing collision detection and correction.  I don't know whether or how one could force the detection/correction code to run before selecting this, and/or how to get access to it differently that would get the thus-informed data.  But if you can run something separately from the Vagrantfile, the `vagrant port --guest 80` trick (or whatever, for other ports one might use) should get the right information on stdout.

Comment: An "after" trigger could be used to execute the ruby code and write the port to a file.

Comment: Apparently so...  https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/ -- amusingly, this showed up in vagrant version 2.1.0, which was apparently released precisely 2 days before I posted this answer.  :D -- I didn't know about them at the time.